# Parsing Json results in uncaught syntax error

Tags: ajax, json

My browser (chrome) tells me this is what is being returned from the server which I have verified as being valid via JsonLint:

```
[{"Id":"bdd937ef-c0d4-4191-805f-316288144060","Name":"Accessories and Auto Parts, Moto ","L18nName":null,"State":null,"L18n":"1033","Index":0,"LevelId":0,"ImagePath":"/content/img/browse/sm/","Children":[]},{"Id":"b01bde48-6f1d-4168-aee4-a7e62eef7bd0","Name":"Car Rental","L18nName":null,"State":null,"L18n":"1033","Index":0,"LevelId":0,"ImagePath":"/content/img/browse/sm/","Children":[]},{"Id":"c039a467-1709-433f-a316-008f6ae301fb","Name":"Car Sales ","L18nName":null,"State":null,"L18n":"1033","Index":0,"LevelId":0,"ImagePath":"/content/img/browse/sm/","Children":[]}]
```

If I just copy this content into a script var it will also parse correctly.

However if i try and parse this content, as returned from the server, into an object I get an Uncaught Syntax error:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Browse/SubCategoryLister/",
                    data: { rfqID: parentRfqId },
                    dataType: "json"
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    rp.hide();
                    sc.show();
                    console.log(data);
                    var status = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(status);
                });
```

On the line

```
var status = JSON.parse(data);
```

However

```
console.log(data);
```

seems to produce a valid object that I can interrogate via developer tools:

[image]

So it seems like the data is already a json object? So Im not quite sure what is going on here. I thought it might have something to do with response headers but this payload is being sent down with an:

Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8

header just like in other pages in the application where i use JSON.parse(data); to create a JSON object from server returned data. So what is the difference here and why cant I parse it? If it's already a JSON object then how an where was it created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You parse json twice. Data parameters `function (data)` is already javascript object, because you've used `dataType: "json"`. From [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

You don't need to call `var status = JSON.parse(data);`. Just use `data` as you'd use result of `JSON.parse`.

#### Update

Also if your server return json content type, then jQuery will choose `dataType` to be `"json"`. From docs:

> If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

Comment: I thought about this but if I take the dataType: "json" out it still fails and console.log(data) still "passes".

Comment: So you're saying that when you remove `dataType: "json"` you still get javascript object in `data`. Right? This might be happening if your server returns "json" content type. See my updated answer. If you want to explicitly parse json in `.done(...)` then set `dataType: "text` or make server return "Content-type: text/plain".

Comment: Yes that's right. The server is ASP.NET MVC returning a JsonResult which is why I checked the headers but in the cases where I need to JSON.parse() and in this case where I don't the response headers etc are the same so I'm stumped. Its not holding me back and I don't need to explicitly parse it but I sure would like to know why it's happening. I'll mark yours as the answer and double triple check my headers etc. To me the only "signaling" that could be happening is via the response headers.

Comment: You might also want to read jQuery ajax page https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. May be I'm missing something. But I don't expect undocumented behavior here. Hope that'll help.